# How do I make my navbar thinner?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to change the navbar such that there's less white space above/below the text. I already tried creating a negative buffer but that didn't seem to work.

Also if anybody knows how to change the navbar to a button(as often mobile sites have) so that it doesn't take up the entire height of the page that would be useful.

[image]

```css
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-width: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(150, 155, 155, );
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">

  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>
  <link href="Calums2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<body>

<div class="list" style="Position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px;">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="Home.html"><h2>Home</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html"><h2>Team</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="kyrgyzstan.html"><h2>Kyrgyzstan</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="Blog.html"><h2>Blog</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="Expeditions.html"><h2>Expeditions</h2></a></li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
        </nav>
       <style>
      text-align:justify;
       </style>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The structure of your HTML code is also not valid.

Comment: As Maihan said, there are problems with your HTML code that prevent a simple and tested answer without re-coding your HTML for you. Something like Johannes answer should work but honestly, the spacing looks perfect in the image you included, I would leave it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it.

```
ul.nav li a>h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ypfhs1gn/1/

Also, to fix your HTML:

```
<div class="list" style="Position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px;">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="Home.html"><h2>Home</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html"><h2>Team</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="kyrgyzstan.html"><h2>Kyrgyzstan</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="Blog.html"><h2>Blog</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="Expeditions.html"><h2>Expeditions</h2></a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: Additionally, here's that fiddle updated to get you that menu button: https://jsfiddle.net/ypfhs1gn/2/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="Home.html"><h2>Home</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="team.html"><h2>Team</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="kyrgyzstan.html"><h2>Kyrgyzstan</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="Blog.html"><h2>Blog</h2></a></li>
        <li><a href="Expeditions.html"><h2>Expeditions</h2></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd try setting up a CSS rule for `nav > ul` containing top/bottom margin and/or padding settings, starting from 0 and (if that has an effect) then changing it to a value you like.